# Generic jsonb to table

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

No matter how I search I cannot find a query that will take any *flat* array of jsonb objects and turn it into a table without referencing individual keys of the jsonb object.

Basically going from

| id | data (jsonb) |
| --- | --- |
| 14 | {"any":1,"flat":2, "structure": "three"} |
| 15 | {"any":4,"flat":"five", "structure": 6} |

to

| id | any | flat | structure |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | "1" | "2" | "three" |
| 15 | "4" | "five" | "6" |

---

##### Edit

**What's the point?**
I want to be able to ingest data from any IoT sensor type without making assumptions of its data structure, i.e. schemaless. At a later stage I want to be able to query this data using vanilla SQL.

From an architectural point of view it's moving the problem of data conformance from having to be done *before* ingestion, to doing *after* ingestion. Basically trading performance for flexibility.

Comment: have you tried the 'jsonb_each_text' function yet?

Comment: If you don't know the property name how can you make columns? SQL queries have columns that are fixed upfront, before the query is run.

Comment: @Yoji No, can you provide an example?

Comment: @Charlieface I'd guess by using some sort of dynamic sql statement.

Comment: But every row might be different. You might eg have 1000 different properties, how could you show that?

Comment: @Charlieface stefanov.sm's solution below does exactly that. It's just a matter of joining his queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you might need this but here is it in two steps.

- First, examine the JSON structure and make a record definition out of it

```sql
select string_agg(format('%I text', k), ', ') 
from jsonb_object_keys((select "data" from the_table limit 1)) k;
-- result: "any" text, flat text, structure text
```

- Second, use this definition and `jsonb_to_record` to flatten the table

```sql
select id, l.*
from the_table 
cross join lateral jsonb_to_record("data") 
as l ("any" text, flat text, structure text);
-- use the result of the above query in the brackets
```

The verbose `cross join lateral` is for clarity, it may be replaced by a comma.

DB-Fiddle [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vYxo8h3UHBwVevt36bGBh2/1)

**Edit:** You may also generate the query to use it as dynamic SQL or invoke it from the upper tier:

```sql
select format(
'select id, l.*
 from the_table, jsonb_to_record("data") 
 as l(%s)',
 (
   select string_agg(format('%I text', k), ', ') 
   from jsonb_object_keys((select "data" from the_table limit 1)) k
 )
);
```

The resulting SQL text is the same as above:

```sql
select id, l.*
 from the_table, jsonb_to_record("data") 
 as l ("any" text, flat text, structure text)
```

Comment: Splendid! Is it possible to bake the steps into a single query (and I'll mark as solved)? Regarding "I am not sure why you might need this" I added a motivation to the question.

Comment: I am afraid that I can not do that yet I see that your motivation makes a lot of sense. Are you planning for different sensor types data to go into separate tables? If so then I would make a view for each sensor type ontop of its 'schemaless' table by generating a separate query per sensor type. In fact I can write a `setof record` returning function but you still have to write an individual record type per sensor type whenever you call it.

Comment: It's been five days and nothing new has come up. I'll mark this as a solution even though it's not ideal.